# Deserialize part of a block of json using Json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm looking for a good way to deserialize part of a block of json. I'm using Json.Net. I tried walking through using a JsonTextReader until I found the chunk I'm looking for and passing that into JsonSerializer but it seems to try to deserialize from the beginning of the stream. I don't care about any of the json except the 'data' near the end.

```
"jquery":[
  [0, 1, "call", ["#form-t3_iqhw5ili"]],
  [1, 2, "attr", "find"],
  [2, 3, "call", [".status"]],
  [3, 4, "attr", "hide"],
  [4, 5, "call", []],
  [5, 6, "attr", "html"],
  [6, 7, "call", [""]],
  [7, 8, "attr", "end"],
  [8, 9, "call", []],
  [1, 10, "attr", "find"],
  [10, 11, "call", ["textarea"]],
  [11, 12, "attr", "attr"],
  [12, 13, "call", ["rows", 3]],
  [13, 14, "attr", "html"],
  [14, 15, "call", [""]],
  [15, 16, "attr", "val"],
  [16, 17, "call", [""]],
  [0, 18, "attr", "insert_things"],
  [18, 19, "call", [
        [{
              "data":{
                 "content":"<div class=\"thing id-t1_c25u9i3 even odd comment \" onclick=\"click_thing(this)\"><p class=\"parent\"><a name=\"c25u9i3\" ></a></p><div class=\"midcol likes\" ><div class=\"arrow upmod\" onclick=\"$(this).vote('f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0', null, event)\" ></div><div class=\"arrow down\" onclick=\"$(this).vote('f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0', null, event)\" ></div></div><div class=\"entry likes\"><div class=\"collapsed\" style='display:none'><a href=\"#\" class=\"expand\" onclick=\"return showcomment(this)\">[+]</a><a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/user/KerrickLong\" class=\"author gray submitter id-t2_4appr\" >KerrickLong</a><span class=\"userattrs\">&#32;[<a class=\"submitter\" title=\"submitter\" href=\"/r/MostlyHarmless/comments/iqhw5/changelog_mostly_harmless_v041_released/\">S</a>]</span>&#32;<span class=\"score dislikes\">-1 points</span><span class=\"score unvoted\">0 points</span><span class=\"score likes\">1 point</span>&#32;<time title=\"Fri Jul 15 16:57:16 2011 GMT\" datetime=\"2011-07-15T16:57:16.209277+00:00\">91 milliseconds</time>&#32;ago &nbsp;<a href=\"#\" class=\"expand\" onclick=\"return showcomment(this)\">(0 children)</a></div><div class=\"noncollapsed\" ><p class=\"tagline\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"expand\" onclick=\"return hidecomment(this)\">[&ndash;]</a><a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/user/KerrickLong\" class=\"author submitter id-t2_4appr\" >KerrickLong</a><span class=\"userattrs\">&#32;[<a class=\"submitter\" title=\"submitter\" href=\"/r/MostlyHarmless/comments/iqhw5/changelog_mostly_harmless_v041_released/\">S</a>]</span>&#32;<span class=\"score dislikes\">-1 points</span><span class=\"score unvoted\">0 points</span><span class=\"score likes\">1 point</span>&#32;<time title=\"Fri Jul 15 16:57:16 2011 GMT\" datetime=\"2011-07-15T16:57:16.209277+00:00\">91 milliseconds</time>&#32;ago</p><form action=\"#\" class=\"usertext\" onsubmit=\"return post_form(this, 'editusertext')\" id=\"form-t1_c25u9i38va\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"thing_id\" value=\"t1_c25u9i3\"/><div class=\"usertext-body\"><div class=\"md\"><p>Hey!</p><p><strong><a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">search!</a></strong></p></div>\n</div><div class=\"usertext-edit\" style=\"display: none\"><div><textarea rows=\"1\" cols=\"1\" name=\"text\" >test&#32;comment</textarea></div><div class=\"bottom-area\"><span class=\"help-toggle toggle\" style=\"display: none\"><a class=\"option active \" href=\"#\" tabindex=\"100\" onclick=\"return toggle(this, helpon, helpoff)\" >formatting help</a><a class=\"option \" href=\"#\">hide help</a></span><span class=\"error TOO_LONG field-text\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error RATELIMIT field-ratelimit\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error NO_TEXT field-text\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error TOO_OLD field-parent\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error DELETED_COMMENT field-parent\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error DELETED_LINK field-parent\" style=\"display:none\"></span><span class=\"error USER_BLOCKED field-parent\" style=\"display:none\"></span><div class=\"usertext-buttons\"><button type=\"submit\" onclick=\"\" class=\"save\" style='display:none'>save</button><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"cancel_usertext(this)\" class=\"cancel\" style='display:none'>cancel</button><span class=\"status\"></span></div></div><table class=\"markhelp md\" style=\"display: none\"><tr style=\"background-color: #ffff99; text-align: center\"><td><em>you type:</em></td><td><em>you see:</em></td></tr><tr><td>*italics*</td><td><em>italics</em></td></tr><tr><td>**bold**</td><td><b>bold</b></td></tr><tr><td>[reddit!](http://reddit.com)</td><td><a href=\"http://reddit.com\">reddit!</a></td></tr><tr><td>* item 1<br/>* item 2<br/>* item 3</td><td><ul><li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li></ul></td></tr><tr><td>&gt; quoted text</td><td><blockquote>quoted text</blockquote></td></tr><tr><td>Lines starting with four spaces<br/>are treated like code:<br/><br/><span class=\"spaces\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>if 1 * 2 &lt 3:<br/><span class=\"spaces\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>print \"hello, world!\"<br/></td><td>Lines starting with four spaces<br/>are treated like code:<br/><pre>if 1 * 2 &lt 3:<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;print \"hello, world!\"</pre></td></tr><tr><td>~~strikethrough~~</td><td><strike>strikethrough</strike></td></tr><tr><td>super^script</td><td>super<sup>script</sup></td></tr></table></div></form><ul class=\"flat-list buttons\"><li class=\"first\"><a href=\"http://www.reddit.com/r/MostlyHarmless/comments/iqhw5/changelog_mostly_harmless_v041_released/c25u9i3\" class=\"bylink\" rel=\"nofollow\" >permalink</a></li><li><a class=\"edit-usertext\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return edit_usertext(this)\">edit</a></li><li><form class=\"toggle del-button\" action=\"#\" method=\"get\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"executed\" value=\"deleted\"/><span class=\"option active\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"return toggle(this)\">delete</a></span><span class=\"option error\">are you sure? &#32;<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"yes\" onclick='change_state(this, \"del\", hide_thing)'>yes</a>&#32;/&#32;<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" class=\"no\" onclick=\"return toggle(this)\">no</a></span></form></li><li><form action=\"/post/remove\" method=\"post\" class=\"state-button remove-button\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"executed\" value=\"removed\" /><span><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return change_state(this, 'remove');\">remove</a></span></form></li><li class=\"toggle\"><form method=\"post\" action=\"/post/distinguish\"><input type=\"hidden\" value=\"distinguishing...\" name=\"executed\"/><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return toggle_distinguish_span(this)\">distinguish</a><span class=\"option error\">distinguish this? &#32;<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return set_distinguish(this, 'yes')\">yes</a>&#32;/&#32;<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return set_distinguish(this, 'no')\">no</a>&#32; /&#32;<a class=\"nonbutton\" href=\"/help/moderation#Distinguishing\">help</a>&#32;</span></form></li><li><a class=\"\" href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"return reply(this)\">reply</a></li></ul></div></div><div class=\"child\" ></div><div class=\"clearleft\"><!--IE6sux--></div></div><div class=\"clearleft\"><!--IE6sux--></div>",
                 "contentHTML":"<div class=\"md\"><p>Hey!</p><p><strong><a href=\"http://www.google.com/\">search!</a></strong></p></div>",
                 "contentText":"Hey!\n\n**[search!](http://www.google.com/)**",
                 "id":"t1_c25u9i3",
                 "link":"t3_iqhw5",
                 "parent":"t3_iqhw5",
                 "replies":""
              },
              "kind":"t1"
           }],
        false
     ]
  ],
```

I have a class for the data as well:

```
public class AddCommentData
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string contentHTML { get; set; }
    public string contentText { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string replies { get; set; }
}
```

Best practices here?

**edit:** 
I tried something like this...

```
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(results));
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.Value != null)
            {
                if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && reader.Value.ToString() == "data")
                {
                    return serializer.Deserialize<AddCommentData>(reader);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: if you post your JSONTextReader code someone might be able to spot something in what you're doing that could help

Comment: I've never used JSON.Net but I would be rather impressed if it was able to parse partial data. Surely you need the entire tree to be able to parse the object no?

Comment: @MaximGershkovich I think the problem here is that there is other data outside of the 'data' object. Assuming your json is always in this format have you considered using conventional string processing to get the 'data' object into it's own string and then using Deserialize<AddCommentData> on it.